# C# Duplicate strings with a little change within line

Tags: c#, string, duplicates, duplication

For example i have strings of array like this. Below is the string of Example[0]

```
Name\r\n
Gamma\r\n
ID\r\n
3F97\r\n
CAR\r\n
Mitsubishi EVO LAN V\r\n
```

well i would like to duplicate this value from this string into Example[0]

```
Name\r\n
Gamma\r\n
ID\r\n
3F97\r\n
CAR\r\n
Mitsubishi EVO LAN V\r\n
Name\r\n
Gamma\r\n
ID\r\n
3F98\r\n
CAR\r\n
Mitsubishi EVO LAN V\r\n
```

is there anyway to do this?
note that the change is below the ID from **3F97** into **3F98**

Comment: What have you tried? [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) is the string MSDN, with what do you have difficulties?

Comment: is it always a change in 4th line?

Comment: i try regex but kind of lost to find it:(, yes it always on the fourth line

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string by end-of-line, change the fourth line, join it and concatenate it to the first string.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question might be giving the wrong impression, correct me if I'm wrong, but what you have here is a class that defines a 'car'.

Why then don't you just create an actual class to represent a car and implement a ToString() method?

```
public class Car {

    public string Name {get;set}
    public string ID {get;set;}
    public string CAR {get;set;}

    public Car(string name,string id,string car){
        Name = name;
        ID = id;
        CAR = car;
    }

    public override string ToString(){
        return string.format("Name: {0}, ID: {1}, CAR: {2}",Name,ID,CAR);
    }
}
```

Then, instead of an array of strings, have an array of cars, which you can duplicate as you please and modify if necessary.

You will also have a central place to modify the format of the output, i.e. the `Car` class definition (even though in normal circumstances, I would never promote a ToString() method like this for output, other than that directed to a logger)